# GetJSON jquery returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getjson, buttonclick

I am trying to get my search box to work and do a getJSON on text search and title. but in the console log, I get text=undefined?title=undefined. so it is not displaying any JSON. Not sure if my click is working correctly or if I have to make my JSON objects?

Script

```
 <script>
     var searchstring = $('input[type="text"]', this).val();
     var url = "https://data.edu/api/v1/metadata";

     url += "?text=" + searchstring;
     url += "?title=" + searchstring;


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type="button"]').click(function(event){

           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,

            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
                  var items = res.data.metadata;
                  var ins = "";
                  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                    ins += "<div>";
                    ins += "Title" + items[i].title;
                    ins += "Title" + items[i].title;
                    ins += "Title" + items[i].title;
                    ins += "</div><br />";
                  };
                  $('#results').html(ins);
                }

            });         
        });
     });

  </script>
```

html

```
              <form class="destinations-form"  role="search" >
                 <div class="input-line">
                    <input id="searchForm"  type="text"  class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Search Documents" />

                    <button type="button"  class="form-submit btn btn-special"  "</button>

                 </div>
              </form>
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="hero-text align-center">
                     <div id="results"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

json

```
data: [
    {
        collection_id: "ADGM-1552427432270-483",
        metadata:{
                   year: "2019",
                   files: text ,
                   title: text,
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you only read the values from the field when the page first loads and it is empty. To fix this, move that logic inside the `click` handler.

The next issue is that you should remove `this` from `$('input[type="text"]', this)`. You don't need a contextual selector here, and this one is incorrect regardless.

Also note that a valid querystring starts with `?` and separates each value with `&`, so your `url` concatenation needs to be amended slightly. In addition you shouldn't update the `url` value on every click. If you do it this way your AJAX request will only work once.

Lastly the `metadata` in your response is an object, not an array. `data` is the array so you need to loop over that instead. The loop can also be simplified by using `map()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const url = "https://data.edu/api/v1/metadata";

  $('button[type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
    let searchstring = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    let requestUrl = url + `?text=${searchstring}&title=${searchstring}`;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: requestUrl,
      success: function(res) {
        let html = res.data.map(item => `<div>Title ${item.metadata.title}</div><br />`);
        $('#results').html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So I tried your code and I still get the same problem. It still seems to not be linking the text from the search bar to the url.

Comment: Check the console for errors. When I make a request to that domain I get an error saying the site is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks, there was an other issue which I just edited the question to address. Tested as working: https://jsfiddle.net/8k23nvqc/.

Comment: great! thank you! I know this is another issue but when I press enter it doesn't search anything. Is that another call I will have to make?

Comment: No, that's because you're using a `type="button"` control. Change it to a `type="submit"` and instead of listening for the click of the button change your jQuery code to listen for the `submit` event of the `form`. Here's an example of how to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/v9jftzsb/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209956/discussion-between-lbook-and-rory-mccrossan).